# How to pass a vector to the dots (...) argument of a function

Tags: r

Several R functions have and arguement `...` that allows you to pass an arbitrary number of arguments. A example of this is the `paste` function, to which you can provide an arbitrary number of arguements. But sometimes, you don't know ahead of time how many arguements you want to pass.

For example, say I want to produce a plot in ggplot, where I want to color points by the combination of two columns:

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), 
                 y=rnorm(100), 
                 cat1=sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 100),
                 cat2=sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 100),
                 cat3=sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 100))
ggplot(df) + aes(x=x, y=y, col=paste(cat1,cat2) + geom_point()
```

But now consider that I want to the list of columns to be colour by to be determined at run-time. I would like to write a function that did something like:

```
library(rlang)
color_plot <- function(df, color_by) {
    color_by = lapply(color_by, sym)
    ggplot(df) + aes(x=x, y=y, col=paste(...=color_by)) + geom_point()
}

color_plot(df, list("cat1"))
color_plot(df, list("cat2", "cat3"))
color_plot(df, list("cat1", "cat2", "cat3"))
```

I guess i'm look for something equivalent to pythons `*args` as in:

```
args =[1,2,3]
my_fun(*args)
```

Comment: `?do.call`, e.g., `do.call(what = paste, args = ...)`. Though I still don't think that will work so well inside a `ggplot` aesthetic mapping - `paste` returns a character string a `aes()` expects unquoted column names.

Comment: I think you're missing a parenthesis for `aes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `syms`:

```
color_plot <- function(df, color_by) {
    color_by <- syms(color_by)
    ggplot(df) + aes(x=x, y=y, col=paste(!!!color_by)) + geom_point()
}
```

Comment: This only works if used in a tidyeval aware environment. So I can't just do
x <- paste(!!!color_by), even if all the variables in color_by are in the current env.

Comment: Yes, that is how rlang works and your question did include library(rlang) so that was the assumption you were making.  A base solution would be:    `color_by <- do.call("paste", df[unlist(color_by)])` and then use `col=color_by` in the last line. of the function.

Comment: Yeah, the particular problem I was trying to solve was a ggplot one, so this is what I was looking for and I had an idea rlang would be the way to do it, but once I'd come across it I was like 'wow, this is great, where else can I use it'.

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be to use `quos` if you prefer passing in unquoted column names instead of a list:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)

color_plot <- function(df, ...) {
  color_by = quos(...)
  ggplot(df) + aes(x=x, y=y, col=paste(!!!color_by)) + geom_point()
}

color_plot(df, cat1, cat2, cat3)
```